# Error UPDATE con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, pdo

Estoy tratando de actualizar los datos, pero al actualizarlo me cambia el id_usuario pero yo quiero seguir consevandolo.

Función,

```
public function actualizaPagador($id_pago,$id_usuario,$pago){
        $db=BaseDatos::conectar();

        try{
            $sentencia = $db->prepare("UPDATE Pagos SET id_pagos=:id_pagos,id_usuario=:id_usuario,iban=:iban,estado=:estado,tipo=:tipo,observaciones=:observaciones,fecha=:fecha,nombre=:nombre,apellido=:apellido,banco=:banco WHERE id_pagos = :id_pagos");
            $sentencia->execute([':id_pagos'=>$id_pago,':id_usuario'=>$id_usuario,':iban'=>$pago->getIban(),':estado'=>$pago->getEstado(),':tipo'=>$pago->getTipo(),':observaciones'=>$pago->getObservaciones(),':fecha'=>$pago->getFecha(),':nombre'=>$pago->getNombre(),':apellido'=>$pago->getApellido(),':banco'=>$pago->getBanco()]);
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Error -> ".$e->getMessage().'<br>';
            echo "Error -> ".$e->getLine().'<br>';
        }
    }
```

Controlador,

```
    elseif(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'editPagador')){
    echo "HOLA va al controlador suuuu";

    $contador=count($_POST['nombrePagador']);
    for ($i=0; $i < $contador ; $i++) {
        $pagador=['id_pagos' => $_POST['id_pagos'][$i],'id_usuario' => $_POST['id_usuario'][$i],'banco'=>$_POST['banco'][$i],'nombre' => $_POST['nombrePagador'][$i],'apellido' => $_POST['apellidoPagador'][$i],'iban' => $_POST['iban'][$i],'fecha' => $_POST['fecha'][$i],'tipo' => $_POST['tipo'][$i],'estado' => $_POST['estado'][$i]];
        echo "<br><br>";
        //print_r($pagador);
        $pago->setIdPago($pagador['id_pagos']);
        $pago->setIdUsuario($pagador['id_usuario']);
        $pago->setNombre($pagador['nombre']);
        $pago->setApellido($pagador['apellido']);
        $pago->setFecha($pagador['fecha']);
        $pago->setTipo($pagador['tipo']);
        $pago->setEstado($pagador['estado']);
        $pago->setIban($pagador['iban']);
        $pago->setBanco($pagador['banco']);
        echo "<h1>".$pagador['id_usuario']."hello</h1>";
        //$pago->setIban($_POST['iban'][$i]);

        // foreach ($pagador as $key => $value) {

        // }
        echo $pagador['id_pagos'].'<br>';

        $lista = $crud->actualizaPagador($pagador['id_pagos'],$pagador['id_usuario'],$pago);

        var_dump($lista);
    }

}
```

Comment: Si no quieres cambiar el valor de `id_usuario` al hacer el UPDATE, simplemente borra `id_usuario=:id_usuario` de tu sentencia SQL.

Comment: Y si quieres ser más estricto puedes añadir el id de usuario como condición del where, además de quitarlo de los campos a updatear o asegurarte de que es igual al preexistente antes de updatear.

Comment: Buenos días Ferni! Muchas gracias, ahora funciona. Creía que tenía seguir el orden.

Comment: Buenos días @Carmen gracias por tu respuesta pero ya he solucionado el problema. Un saludo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo ponga los valores que desea cambiar  en su sentencia UPDATE, como el id_usuario no es variable no tiene necesidad de enviarlo dentro del SET, por lo que podria intentar:

```
 $sentencia = $db->prepare("UPDATE Pagos SET iban=:iban,estado=:estado,tipo=:tipo,observaciones=:observaciones,fecha=:fecha,nombre=:nombre,apellido=:apellido,banco=:banco WHERE id_pagos = :id_pagos");
```

**NOTA**: también he eliminado  "id_pagos=:id_pagos" ya que supongo que esta es la llave primaria de la tabla y esta no debe varias.